# Better way writing nested for loops in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Please suggest better way(more of elixir way) of writing following C code into elixir.

```
int some_num = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
    for(int k = 0; k < 10000; k++){
      some_num += 1;
    }
  }
}
printf("%d", some_num);
```

And **can** it be implemented with getting benefits elixir concurrency?

EDIT:
Bit of background, I am fresh to elixir and still learning. The main motive of the question was to write more idiomatic elixir code than applying concurrency.

Comment: increment is an operation that can be done in isolation - so it is atypical of the tasks that Elixir is used for.  But you could partition each inner loop in to say 4 separate erlang/elixir processes and gather their result by receiving messages from the process when each finished.  I say for since my pc has 4 cores. ymmv.

Comment: A state-of-the-art approach to concurrency in Elixir is to adopt the Flow module https://github.com/antonmi/flowex but adapting your example to use it means changing the code to per a lot more Elixir idiomatic first.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff: you have pointed to wrong [Flow](https://github.com/plataformatec/flow) library.

Comment: If you could point to right one - I couldn't find how to use the Flow module without invoking mix etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplest way to implement exactly what you have written is to use `for` macro:

```
sum =
  for i <- 0..100,
      j <- 0..1_000,
      k <- 0..10_000,
      reduce: 0 do
    acc -> acc + 1
  end
```

**EDIT:**

`:reduce` option is available in new versions of Elixir (1.8+). In older versions you can use nested `Enum.reduce/3`:

```
Enum.reduce(0..100, 0, fn _, acc ->
  acc + Enum.reduce(0..1_000, 0, fn _, acc ->
    acc + Enum.reduce(0..10_000, 0, fn _, acc ->
      acc + 1
    end)
  end)
end)
```

---

About second part of the question: **no**, this loop would not gain much from the concurrency, and if it would change times in any way then it will be only slower. In this particular case it could be written as `sum = 100 * 1_000 * 10_000` which could be faster as could be easily optimized by the compiler to `10_000_000` (IIRC Erlang compiler cannot optimize given loop to the constant).

**TL;DR** such obvious loop cannot be improved by the concurrency and in general case it is hard to say whether processes (aka parallelization) will help or not. It is also very important to remember that `parallel != concurrent`, so you will gain no speedup from running `N` Erlang's processes on machine with `N-1` schedulers (by default number of CPUs).

Comment: where does the `for` macro come from?  Elixir shell gives  `(CompileError) iex:3: unsupported option :reduce given to for` for the code you posted otherwise.

Comment: [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1), probably you have older version of the Elixir that do not support `:reduce` option.

Comment: Hi @Hauleth  in the real world (my 4 core Win10 PC) your code takes ages even to return a prompt - while the code I give terminates after 16 secs.

Comment: Because Erlang optimizations aren't that good yet. In theory (and in some compilers in practice) it will be [optimized out](https://godbolt.org/z/acQ-jR) to single constant. Still in this toy code it can gain something because of that, but in the end Elixir want to compile directly to BEAM IR and then such code could be optimized out, by introducing processes you will prevent such optimization. And as it was said earlier, it can be written in better way, so the whole question makes little to no sense at all.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the new `:reduce` option.  Weird syntax with the arrows going every which way--it's like you have a single branch `case` statement inside the `for`. There are [nice examples](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) of the for `options` in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Below is a working  example on how you could achieve concurrency for your rather  toy problems of achieving 1000000000 increment operations - in case you are curious about how it can be done.**

The code below spawns 100 Elixir processes corresponding to your outer loop.  The inside code - those 2 nested loops - (written in more idiomatic form using `Enum.reduce`[see](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)) is thus ran concurrently (as possible by the VM).  The results of each process are sent to a dedicated receiver process that counts down starting from 100 whenever it receives a new result. Each subtotal get added to the grand total which is then printed out when 100 subtotals have been received. 
To test: Save the code as a file `nested.ex` and compile in the Elixir shell using `c nested.ex`. The run it in that shell using `Main.main` .  You should see the following output:

```
iex(4)> Main.main    
:ok
total = 1000000000
```

with the `ok` coming a few second before the `total`.  You should also experience high cpu multi-core usage.

```
defmodule Main do 
def main(  ) do
    pid = spawn fn -> Receiver.loop( 100,0 ) end
    1..100 |> Enum.each( fn x -> spawn (fn -> Nested.run(pid) end ) end)
  end

end

#################################
defmodule Nested do
 def run(pid) do
    sub_total= 
    Enum.reduce( 1..1000, 0, fn x, acc_n -> acc_n +
      Enum.reduce( 1..10000, 0, fn y, acc_m -> acc_m + 1  end )
    end )
   send pid, sub_total
   Process.exit(self(), :kill )
 end
end

#################################
defmodule Receiver do
 def loop(0, total) do
   IO.puts "total = #{total}"
   Process.exit(self(), :kill )
 end
 #
 def loop(count_down, total ) do # count down to zero collecting totals
    receive do
      sub_total ->
        loop(count_down-1, sub_total + total)
    end
 end
end
#################################
```

Parallelism can be obtained to **gain advantage** over pure concurrency by judiciously converting from plain `spawn` to `Node.spawn` [see docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Node.html#spawn/2)

**Informal Speed test** 
Testing on my Win10 PC that reports:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) ..
```

The code I give here computes the result in 16s where as that of @Hauleth takes over 10 minutes  - since his seems to get allocated just a single core where mine gets all 4.

Comment: Why have you spawned so much processes?

Comment: @Hauleth that's theElixir/Erlang way - `spawn`  many mini-processes and let the VM sort out the concurrency optimization.  100 is not that many. See also https://www.poeticoding.com/spawning-processes-in-elixir-a-gentle-introduction-to-concurrency/

Comment: I know Erlang and for sure this is neither Erlang way nor any kind of optimization. If anything it can only cause slowdowns. The "Erlang way" is to write `sum = 100 * 1_000 * 10_000`.

Comment: Well then add your answer `sum = 100 * 1_000 * 10_000` and see if it is accepted!

Comment: [`spawn` isn't some "golden bullet"](https://www.theerlangelist.com/article/spawn_or_not) for speed improvements, it is meant to do something completely different, otherwise [we end with questions like that](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-many-processes-can-i-create-in-one-cpu-core/21153?u=hauleth) which completely misses the point.

Comment: The original poster asked for concurrency while doing 1000000000 increment operations - nothing more, nothing less - I gave an answer which does that.  Yours does not.

Comment: "can it be implemented with getting **benfits** elixir concurrency" (emphasis mine) and answer for that question is **No**, you will gain no benefits from Elixir's concurrency features in such simple case. In more complex case - maybe, maybe not, it depends.

Comment: Hauleth GavinBrelstaff  I am new to elixir and was just curious how to write more idiomatic nested loops in elixir and **can** we get any benefit with elixir's concurrency.

Comment: Unfortunately such trivial problems will almost never get you a real world answer. This just shows one way you could attempt to get concurrency into your application. This may not be the best solution to all the problems you may come across. If you have a real world scenario in mind, it would be best to ask about that.

Comment: @Hauleth : just to say that the BEAM community continue to advocate the many process approach https://youtu.be/JvBT4XBdoUE?t=403

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff: yes, but not for parallelism or performance gains, but for code organisation and error isolation.